# Having problem with position fixed (background-image)

Tags: html, css

I just started to learn HTML/CSS/JS, and I am trying to embed a background image in my wrapper class for my website.

My main problem is that when I scroll down the page, my background image scrolls down and ultimately disappears. This only occurs on my extended desktop monitor (across Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) but does not occur for my mobile, iPad, and MacBook.

You can notice that a black empty space appears on top of my website in [my example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZvuQ.jpg). (Please understand the image is linked since I am not able to embed images yet being a new stackoverflow user.)

The [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSBPq.png) of how I would like my website to look like (without a black empty space) can be found in this link.

Please let me know if more information is necessary to solve this problem. Thank you.

The CSS code I used to put my background wallpaper is as follows:

```
#wrapper {
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}


#wrapper > .bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../../images/wallpaper.jpg");
    background-color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    /*will-change: transform;*/
    z-index: -1;
}


#wrapper > .bg.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

My HTML code is:

```
<!-- Wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">


<!-- Header -->

<header id="header">
    <a href="index" class="logo">SungJun Cho</a>
</header>
<!-- Nav -->
<nav id="nav">
    <ul class="links">
        <li><a href="index">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="research">Research</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="publications">Publications</a></li>
        <li><a href="education">Teaching & Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="icons">
        <li><a href="mailto:scho20@uchicago.edu" class="icon regular fa-envelope"><span
                    class="label">E-mail</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://github.com/scho97" class="icon brands fa-github"><span class="label">GitHub</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/scho_2020/" class="icon brands fa-instagram"><span
                    class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<!-- Copyright -->
<div id="copyright">
    <ul>
        <li>&copy; SungJun Cho</li>
        <li>Design: <a href="https://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a></li>
        <li>Hosted by <a href="https://pages.github.com/">GitHub Pages</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Share your HTML code please.

Comment: I just added my HTML code in the post above. Thanks.

Comment: There isn't any class named ``bg``. You can add ``position: fixed`` to your ``#wrapper`` instead of adding it to the background image.

Comment: So should I delete `position: fixed` in my `bg`, and change `position: relative` to `position: fixed` directly on my `#wrapper`?

Comment: Can you upload a photo of how you want it to become?

Comment: Yes, I uploaded a photo. Basically, I do not want to have a black empty space when I scroll my page down.

Comment: Is the photo gonna be fixed when you scroll?

Comment: Yes, I would like the photo to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css instead. As I saw you want to have a fixed background image. You must delete the fixed positions from your image and add them to your `#wrapper` and don't forget to set this to your wrapper: `top: 0` `left: 0`.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}


#wrapper > .bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* you can do All in one */
    /*background: url("../../images/wallpaper.jpg") center/cover no-repeat;*/
    background-image: url("../../images/wallpaper.jpg");
    background-color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    /*will-change: transform;*//
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but your suggestion did not work. The background became black, and the page did not scrolled down.

Comment: It still does not change the errors. The background is still black, and the page does not scroll.